# Unix commands with c++

Tags: c++, shell, unix, system

I need to run Unix commands from a C++ program.

```
    string command;
    do{
        cout<<"~ "<<get_current_dir_name ()<<">";
        cin>>command;
        if(command=="exit"||cin.eof()){
            cout<<"exit!"<<endl;
            system("exit");
            break;
        }
        system(command.c_str());
    }while (true);
```

But I get a "Permission denied" error when I use invoke the `cd` command (to change the current directory).

Can I use a `chmod` in my code? If yes, how can I use it.

I'm not able use `chmod` after compilation.

This is how I compile my code:

```
g++ -o shell *.cpp -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-vla -pedantic -march=core2 -Os -pipe -fstack-protector-all -g3 -Wl,-O,1,-z,combreloc
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `system()` function starts a new shell. If you `cd` in that shell you only affect that shell, which goes away once the call to `system()` returns, and so basically has no effect. You should probably never use `system()` in a C++ program - if you want to change the working directory of your executing code, you should use the `chdir()` function which is POSIX but I believe also available on Windows..